# How can I consistently handle vertical scroll bars in table with scrollable tbody?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a `thead` and `tbody`. The table with `thead` is "fixed", but the `div` that contains the table with the `tbody` scrolls. The problem is that I cannot find a consistent way to handle the scroll bars. For example, if the user has (via their system settings) the scrollbars set to always show, then the columns inside the `tbody` are pushed to the left. If they have their scroll bars set to only show on scroll, then it looks fine.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="this_is_fixed">
    <table class="my_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scroll_container">
    <div class="scroll">
        <table class="my_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Col 1</td>
                    <td>Col 2</td>
                    <td>Col 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.this_is_fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
} 

.scroll_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}   

.scroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.my_table thead tr th {
     width: 33.33333%   
}

.my_table tbody tr td {
     width: 33.33333%   
}
```

The table inside `.scroll` is shifted to the left if the user has their scrollbars set to always show, but is fine if they have it set to only show scrollbars when scrolling. Is there a consistent way for me to handle this (cross browser)? I don't want solutions that involve hiding the scroll bars. Thanks in advance for any solutions!

Comment: Ok so, it's quite simple. Your container must include the fixed bar. In your example it's outside.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution #1:  Avoid the effect that scrollbars have on width

This is a very simple solution to avoid scrollbars from having an effect on the width of your page.

```
html {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

### Solution #2:  Always show scrollbars

This is a widely used method to always show scrollbars.

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

To always show an active scrollbar, make the height 101%...

```
html {
    height: 101%;
}
```

Example - always showing scrollbar:

```css
html {
    height: 101%;
}
.this_is_fixed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
} 

.scroll_container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}   

.scroll {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.my_table thead tr th {
     width: 33.33333%   
}

.my_table tbody tr td {
     width: 33.33333%   
}
```

```html
<div class="this_is_fixed">
    <table class="my_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scroll_container">
    <div class="scroll">
        <table class="my_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Col 1</td>
                    <td>Col 2</td>
                    <td>Col 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue, in a generic sense, comes up often. For instance, when a full-screen overlay is used to hide the content behind a modal dialog. We might set the page to hide overflow to match the overlay size and prevent scrolling from interfering with the desired appearance. As a result, a scrollbar that was there suddenly disappears and the screen "jumps" as all the content shifts.

As with the way Bootstrap addresses the problem, the most robust solution is to measure the scrollbar width using JS and a dummy/hidden div that will always increase it's size to include the scrollbar if the useragent is configured to show them. Then you can adjust your margins, etc, to account for that width (you would also need to determine whether the content is overflowing its container, otherwise you'll adjust for a scrollbar that isn't there.) Easy enough with a some additional JS, but you'd have to recheck anytime the window resizes or the table content changes.

Anyway, borrowing some code from https://github.com/stempler/bootstrap

```
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

--

```
function measureScrollbar() {
  var scrollDiv = angular.element('<div class="'+MEASURE_SCROLLBAR_CLASS+'"></div>');
  bodyEl.append(scrollDiv);
  var width = scrollDiv[0].offsetWidth - scrollDiv[0].clientWidth;
  console.log('measureScrollbar', width);
  scrollDiv.remove();
  return width;
}
```

There may be a much simpler solution that involves creative CSS to force everything to align, but I'm not seeing it at the moment since you have everything relative positioned within absolute containers. This answer more-or-less just addresses the general problem of "I don't want things to shift when a scrollbar appears".